How to solve Alternate page with proper canonical tag on search console - All Error related to query parameters?
I have found multiple error of Alternate page with proper canonical tag in search console. So how to disallow those query parameters in robots.txt file
Error on these pages:
https://example.com/es/ads/car/maruti?with_media=1&page=1
I want to added 1 directive from both below mentioned. So, which one would be best for robots file, so that this issues will be remove from my search console.
1---------------
Disallow: /?with_media=
Disallow: /&page=
or
2----------
Disallow: /?with_media=&page=*
Or
If you have any other better option for this then please let me know
